# FaceTime with 2 Phones (work and private) & 1 Apple ID

Tags: iphone, messages, apple-id, facetime

I have 2 phones, one is for work and one is private. I use the same Apple ID on both as I don't want to pay for my movies, apps & music twice. When I'm on the plane/train to another one of our offices or a customer, I really want to have access to the movies and music. My problem is I want to separate FaceTime and iMessage on the phones.

Basically what I want is this.

---

Work phone

- FaceTime: Uses my work phone number as Caller ID and can be reached via that and my work email.
- iMessage: Uses my work phone number.

---

Private phone

- FaceTime: Uses my private phone number as Caller ID and can be reached by that and my private emails.
- iMessage: Uses my private phone number.

---

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apple ID logins on an iOS device are completely independent for these services:

- iTunes & App Store
- iCloud
- iMessage
- FaceTime

You could sign into 4 different Apple IDs for these services on one device and that would work fine.

When you say you use the same Apple ID to not have to pay multiple times for iTunes content, that would suggest you would want to use the same Apple ID for iTunes & App Store, then use a different Apple ID between devices for the other three services.

You can find login/logout options for each of these services in Settings. When setting up a new device, you are given the option to use separate Apple IDs for iTunes & App Store by a small link on the iCloud login prompt.

Comment: This worked like a charm, at least so far.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to maintain separate Apple IDs for work and personal phone. Respective phone number can be associated with it's Apple ID and all the activities can be neatly kept segregated.

If you wish to share movies, music and app purchases, the recommended way is to use [Apple's Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201088) feature.

Comment: I already use the Family Sharing slots with my actual family so this is not an option sadly